# Office server online Error: Word online can't open this document because the service is busy

Tags: office365, preview, ms-wopi

I have setup Office online server in standalone mode(without sharepoint or exchange server). While trying to preview document , I am able to preview excel sheets but not able to preview word or ppt files, getting 
error "Word online can't open this document because the service is busy, Please try again later"
I am using OpenFromURLEnabled feature to test the preview. Here is the URL that generates preview link
http://wacserver/op/generate.aspx.

How can we preview word and ppt document in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The Office Online relies on the SharePoint Shared Services Infrastructure to convert the document into a browser ready rendition. If the front-end machines cannot find the shared services, or the shared services are not started on at least one machine, then viewing the document or presentation will fail with this error.

Another possible cause for these errors is a potential problem with the Service Account running the Web Application, the Word Viewing Service, and the PowerPoint Service.

Read more about that in the [Error when view or edit in browser for Word or PowerPoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/error-when-view-or-edit-in-browser) article.